# How to override product list page

Tags: magento2, layout, template, overrides, product-list

I'm trying to override the list product page. My objective is add certain information on each product above the add to cart button for example.

I already did with the single page product, just overrided `catalog_product_view.xml` and added my block where I wanted.

But with list product I'm watching the `catalog_category_view.xml` and I really don't know how to it.

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
```

`product/list.phtml` This template is doing all the work. So I only think to copy this template on my vendor's module and write my stuff where I want.

Is this the propper way? Can't I only write my block and indicate magento to use it? I don't like to copy all this 'core' template and write inside modifying it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can rewrite the block

Step # 1 – Create a **di.xml** file in a folder **FME/Test/etc**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" type="FME\Test\Block\Rewrite\Product\ListProduct" />
</config>
```

Step # 2 - The next step to overriding Magento2 block is to create a **ListProduct.php** Block file in the folder **FME/Test/Block/Rewrite/Product**

```
<?php
    /**
    * Rewrite Product ListProduct Block
    * @category    FME
    * @package     FME_Test
    * @author      Fme Extensions Development Company
    */

    namespace FME\Test\Block\Rewrite\Product;
    class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
        {
            public function __construct()
                {
                    echo "you can do this in block"; die();
                }
        }
```

[Reference](https://www.fmeextensions.com/blog/override-magento-2-helper-block-model-and-controller/)

**override phtml file**

create checkout_cart_index.xml inside :

`app/code/Webkul/Hello/view/frontend/layout` folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance dc" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Webkul_Hello::cart.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</page>
```

Here,

checkout.cart : is block name, whose template file you want to override.

Webkul_Hello::cart.phtml : is a template file of your module.

Now, create cart.phtml file at location:

`app/code/Webkul/Hello/view/frontend/templates` folder

```
<h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
//write your stuff here
```

[reference](http://webkul.com/blog/override-phtml-file-magento2/)

Comment: Following this solution, I encounter that I have to do all the work in the function: `getProductDetailsHtml` adding my stuff and I don't have so much control. How can I add my custom template in this case?

Comment: @slayerbleast doing module or theme?

Comment: for module, on app/code/...

Comment: @slayerbleast i added the  example for that too...

Answer (score 6):

You have to just write below xml code in your module file,
In your module layout file,

**`app/code/Vendor/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`**
File,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
            <!-- for magento catalog list overrider -->
            <referenceBlock name="category.products.list" template="Vendor_Modulename::product/list.phtml" />          
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: You can override using above method, please let me know if you have any issue

Comment: Unable to over-ride class using this way.