# How to move add to cart button after the short description in product listing page

Tags: magento2, product-listing

How to move add to cart, compare, wish list section after the short description in product listing page.

[image]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/173239/how-to-move-the-add-to-cart-section-under-the-short-description-on-product-view Same way you can do it for product listing page

Comment: It means I have to override catalog_category_view.xml file @SiddheshShirodkar

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148832/how-to-override-product-list-page

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148832/how-to-override-product-list-page

Answer (score 0):

Yes correct. Just make changes as per your requirement in :
Vendor/theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148832/how-to-override-product-list-page got the solution from here